# confuse replacing with React Hooks React Native

Tags: react-native, if-statement, async-await, react-hooks

I was trying to make async await with if condition with React Hooks.
This code below is before I was trying to made it become React Hooks:

```
async startService() {
        if (Platform.OS !== 'android') {
            console.log('Only Android platform is supported');
            return;
        }
        if (Platform.Version >= 26) {
            const channelConfig = {
                id: 'ForegroundServiceChannel',
                name: 'Notification Channel',
                description: 'Notification Channel for Foreground Service',
                enableVibration: true,
                importance: 2
            };
            await VIForegroundService.createNotificationChannel(channelConfig);
        }
    }
```

and I was trying to make it into React Hooks

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function startService() {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'android') {
          console.log('Only Android platform is supported');
          return;
      }
      if (Platform.Version >= 26) {
          const channelConfig = {
              id: 'ForegroundServiceChannel',
              name: 'Notification Channel',
              description: 'Notification Channel for Foreground Service',
              enableVibration: false,
              importance: 2
          };
          await VIForegroundService.createNotificationChannel(channelConfig);
      }
      const notificationConfig = {
          id: 3456,
          title: 'Foreground Service',
          text: 'Foreground service is running',
          icon: 'ic_notification',
          priority: 0
      };
      if (Platform.Version >= 26) {
          notificationConfig.channelId = 'ForegroundServiceChannel';
      }
      await VIForegroundService.startService(notificationConfig);
  }startService();
  }, []);
```

and I was also trying to call it inside my jsx like this:

```
<Button onPress={() => this.startService()}>
      <Text>Tes</Text>
 </Button>
```

and it did not working, did I write it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, scope of the function `startService()` is within the arrow function inside the `useEffect`. It can only be accessed from within the arrow function in the `useEffect`. What you're trying to do is to call a function in a block where it doesn't have a scope.

Second thing, `useEffect` is not something that is to be called explicitly. The effect will be initiated based on the dependency array. Ryan Florance explains beautifully how to use useEffect hook in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpw9EHDh2bM).

To make your code work you do not need useEffect at all. Simply move the function definiton of `startService()` out of the useEffect to somewhere inside the main function or outside of the function (if it doesn't have any other dependencies).

If your aim is to initiate `startService()` exactly once, you can use useEffect in a manner as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    startService();
},[]);
```

Another thing, usage of the `Button` component is not right.
Do something like below:

```
<Button title="Tes" onPress={startService} />
```

Comment: function foregroundService () {
    useEffect(() => {
      const startService = async () =>{
        //if condition
            await VIForegroundService.createNotificationChannel(channelConfig);
        }
        // const notificationconfig
        //if condition
        await VIForegroundService.startService(notificationConfig);
    }; startService();
    }, []);
  } 

I made it like this, please corrent me I really new to this react hooks

Comment: @valverara You should NEVER put useEffect within a function. It is illegal!